# What's the easiest way to clone a MacBook Pro drive with both Mac OS and Windows 7 installed?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook, clone

I have a mid 2009 13" MacBook Pro with the 160 GB drive split in half running both Mac OS and Windows 7 through bootcamp.

I'm planning to replace the hard drive for a 750 GB model and I would like to find the easiest way to clone the drives and resize the partitions so that I don't need to install both OS again. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple, you can use two free apps. The first is [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html), which can clone the mac partition to your new drive. The second is [Winclone](http://download.cnet.com/Winclone/3000-2242_4-11089354.html), which clones your windows partition and lets you restore it on the new drive (all done in OS X). I've used both myself before when I migrated to a larger HDD.